# Django form not saving objects in database

Tags: python, django

My form is not saving any objects in the database. No clue why, tried couple more ways to do it but nothing works.

**in models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class ProductListing(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=False)
    product_image = models.ImageField(blank=True)
    product_description = models.TextField(blank=False)
    product_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=0, blank=True, null=True)
    product_quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=0)
```

**in views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import addproduct_form

def addproduct_page(request, *arg, **kwarg):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = addproduct_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = addproduct_form

    return render(request, 'StaffPages/add_product.html', {'productform' : form})
```

**inside the template**

```
{% block content %}
{% load static %}
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "{% static 'StaffPages/add_product.css' %}"/>
<div class="maincontainer">
    <form class="addproductform">
        <div>{{productform.product_name}}</div>
        <div>{{productform.product_image}}</div>
        <div>{{productform.product_description}}</div>
        <div>{{productform.product_price}}</div>
        <div>{{productform.product_quantity}}</div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to explicitly specify the `POST` method in your form, otherwise, it would be `GET`:

```
<form class="addproductform" method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
    <div>{{productform.product_name}}</div>
    <div>{{productform.product_image}}</div>
    <div>{{productform.product_description}}</div>
    <div>{{productform.product_price}}</div>
    <div>{{productform.product_quantity}}</div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

also, don't forget to put the `{% csrf_token %}`.

Comment: This form don't work without action url. ( If action url  base index("/"), it can be work.)

Comment: @AliYaman The default action url is the **current** url; and there is no need to specify that if you don't want to change it (e.g posting to a form to  a different page).

Comment: how did you know that from the question? what if it's different?

Comment: Although it's usually a _rare_ case, the form context variable (`productform`) is passing to the form from the same view that's responsible for _handling_ the form; so we have same urls here.

Answer (score -1):

The missing ones are;

- Action url
- csrf token

For example;

```
{% block content %}
{% load static %}
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "{% static 'StaffPages/add_product.css' %}"/>
<div class="maincontainer">
    <form action="{% url "app_name:url_name" %}  class="addproductform">{% csrf_token %}
        <div>{{productform.product_name}}</div>
        <div>{{productform.product_image}}</div>
        <div>{{productform.product_description}}</div>
        <div>{{productform.product_price}}</div>
        <div>{{productform.product_quantity}}</div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```